# Python Telebot. Как сделать inline кнопку одноразовой?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Суть в таком: бот отправляет по нажатию кнопки картинку с 2мя инлайн кнопками - лайк и дизлайк. При нажатии на лайк или дизлайк происходит событие - вылежает уведомление и происходит запись в базу. Но на кнопки можно нажимать несклько раз и каждый раз обработчик будет все это обрабатывать. Как сделать, чтобы на лайк или дизлайк можно было нажать один раз, чтобы пользователь запрашивал новую картинку уже.

Вот код по отработке нажатия на лайк

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def query_handler(call):

if call.data == 'like':
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, text='Ты поставил лайк')
```

Как реализовать что то в духе: пользовател снова нажимает на лайк, а ему в ответ - вы уже проголосовали

Comment: Проверять если ли пользователь в базе данных, если есть -- говорить что уже нажали.

Comment: Воодбще я с юзер айди не работаю, пока что в базу передаю кол-во кликов нажавших. Наверное можно как то отработать усовным циклом, по пока идей нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что стоит.

- проверить, голосовал ли пользователь (проверка в БД по `id`)
- записать ответ и `id` пользователя
- удалить или изменить кнопку, чтобы пользователь не нажал ее еще раз

что-то вроде этого:

```
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, 
    message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Принято!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Можешь записывать данные в бд, а можешь просто убирать после нажатия кнопки ->

```
bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=None)
```

зависит от того как работает твой бот